# Read Xml on SQL Server with namespace

Tags: sql-server, xml

I trying to read a XML file in SQL Server using this guide.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/13/sql-server-simple-example-of-reading-xml-file-using-t-sql/

Works fine, but I have a XML file with a namespace and doesn´t works this code with namespace.

Some solution?

---

Thanks Remus. Now I have this code

```
 DECLARE @MyXML XML
SET @MyXML = '<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3"   Moneda="USD">
    <cfdi:Impuestos totalImpuestosRetenidos="0.00" totalImpuestosTrasladados="1143.06">
    </cfdi:Impuestos>
</cfdi:Comprobante> ' 

;with xmlnamespaces('http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3' as cfdi)
SELECT
a.b.value('@Moneda','varchar(100)') Moneda,
a.b.value('Impuestos[1]/@totalImpuestosTrasladados','float') totalImpuestosTraslados
FROM @MyXML.nodes('cfdi:Comprobante') a(b)
```

Works, but the value of totalImpuestosTraslados is NULL.

Moneda  totalImpuestosTraslados

USD     NULL

Answer (score 2):

Use [`WITH XMLNAMESPACES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177607.aspx).  Post details (what you tried, what error you got) if this information is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @MyXML XML
SET @MyXML = '<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3"   Moneda="USD">
    <cfdi:Impuestos totalImpuestosRetenidos="0.00" totalImpuestosTrasladados="1143.06">
    </cfdi:Impuestos>
</cfdi:Comprobante> ' 

;with xmlnamespaces('http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3' as cfdi)
SELECT
a.b.value('@Moneda','varchar(100)') Moneda,
a.b.value('cfdi:Impuestos[1]/@totalImpuestosTrasladados','float') totalImpuestosTraslados
FROM @MyXML.nodes('cfdi:Comprobante') a(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

"Impuestos" also have cfdi as namespace, so you have to include it too

```
DECLARE @MyXML XML
SET @MyXML = '<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3"   Moneda="USD">
<cfdi:Impuestos totalImpuestosRetenidos="0.00" totalImpuestosTrasladados="1143.06">
</cfdi:Impuestos>
</cfdi:Comprobante> ' 

;with xmlnamespaces('http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3' as cfdi)
SELECT
a.b.value('@Moneda','varchar(100)') Moneda,
a.b.value('<b>/cfdi:</b>Impuestos[1]/@totalImpuestosTrasladados','float') totalImpuestosTraslados
FROM @MyXML.nodes('cfdi:Comprobante') a(b)
```